# Ruby pipes: How do I tie the output of two subprocesses together?

Tags: ruby, pipe, popen

Is there an automated way to do shell piping in Ruby? I'm trying to convert the following shell code to Ruby:

```
a | b | c... > ...
```

but the only solution I have found so far is to do the buffer management myself (simplified, untested, hope it gets my meaning across):

```
a = IO.popen('a')
b = IO.popen('b', 'w+')
Thread.new(a, b) { |in, out|
    out.write(in.readpartial(4096)) until in.eof?
    out.close_write
}
# deal with b.read...
```

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to tell popen to use an existing stream, instead of creating a new one? Or alternatively, an IO#merge method to connect a's output to b's input? My current approach becomes rather unwieldly when the number of filters grows.

I know about `Kernel#system('a | b')` obviously, but I need to mix Ruby filters with external program filters in a generic way.

Comment: There is one solution with spawn command in ruby. You should open several pipes and then use spawn options to redirect Stdin and Stdout of child processes. You can find a more detailed example in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898528/marshal-ruby-pipes-sending-serialized-object-to-child-processes/13258047#13258047

Comment: Open3's pipelines seem pretty ideal https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-pipeline_rw

Answer (score 12):

Old question, but since its one of the first result on Google, here is the answer : http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/ruby-subprocesses-part_3/ (method 8)

In short :

```
sh = Shell.new
sh.system("a") | sh.system("b") | sh.system("c")
```

And you can do more complicated things like

```
sh.echo(my_string) | sh.system("wc") > "file_path"
xml = (sh.echo(html) | sh.system("tidy", "-q")).to_s
```

Comment: Starting from Ruby 2.7, 'shell' is no longer a standard library and requires installing a gem. See https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/ (section 'Other notable changes since 2.6')

Answer (score 5):

Using plain ruby, `spawn` has redirection options that you can use to connect processes with pipes.

1) Create a pipe

```
r,w = IO.pipe
```

2) Use it to connect two spawned processes

```
spawn(*%w[echo hello world], out: w)
spawn(*%w[tr a-z A-Z], in: r)
# => HELLO WORLD
```

Of course, you can encapsulate this in something like `sh.system` from the mentioned Shell library, and create a |() method for doing the interconnecting.

The open3 module of the standard library has some really nice tools for this kind of stuff, including the creation of complete pipelines.

Answer (score 3):

If `a`, `b`, and `c` are commands normally accessed from the command-line then you could use:

```
captured_output = `a | b | c`
```

Ruby will run the commands in a sub-shell, and capture STDOUT.

If you need to route the output to a file for some reason, then you can add the redirection to the command too. STDOUT will not be returned to you in that case, but you could open the file and manually process it:

```
`a | b | c > captured_output`
File.foreach('captured_output') do |li|
  print li
end
```

It doesn't offer as much control as using `system` or `popen3` but it's convenient:

```
>> sin, sout, serr = Open3.popen3('ls -al | tail -1') #=> [#<IO:fd 4>, #<IO:fd 5>, #<IO:fd 7>, #<Thread:0x00000100bb8798 run>]
>> sout.read #=> "drwxr-xr-x   3 greg  staff    102 Nov  2 21:01 python\n"
```

Comment: I would also instead of using Threads made it using big loop for everything ... nasty solution for nasty problem

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, piping in shell is a serious matter and, indeed, it would require a fair amount of code. It's not necessary to spawn threads with read/write loops, but it would still require a lot of work.

The simplest example I've found is [redirect implementation in *dash* (Debian Almquist Shell)](https://github.com/chenguo/dash/blob/master/src/redir.c). Generally, if you'd want to do the same in Ruby, you'll need to replicate these *fd* manipulation tricks using Ruby's `IO#dup`, `IO#fileno`, `IO#pipe`, `IO#reopen`, etc. It might be easier to reuse shell (such as dash's) code in C .so library for Ruby interpreter than trying to combine the same thing using just Ruby primitives.

I don't know of any existing generalized Ruby API for complex interprocess piping / redirection. If you could suggest a good API you'd like to use, may be I could participate in implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a super old question, but I just went through this pain.

Basically I came up with a pair of utility methods that run commands with popen within forks, passing results through pipes, to achieve something like:

```
echo 'ABC12345 234234 24523' | wc | grep '1'
```

To do it in Ruby:

```
# Setup two pipes (the two we see in the shell command line above)
# plus one more to receive the result from.
pipe_pair1 = IO.pipe
pipe_pair2 = IO.pipe
pipe_pair_result = IO.pipe
pipe_in_out nil, pipe_pair1,  ['echo', 'ABC12345 234234 24523']
pipe_in_out pipe_pair1, pipe_pair2, ['wc']
pipe_in_out pipe_pair2, pipe_pair_result, ['grep', '1']

# Get the result from the final pipe
puts "Output: #{pipe_result(pipe_pair_result)}"
```

The code for the methods is on this gist: https://gist.github.com/philayres/c0d96cd263329e41fa84c2e3c7b9ae7b