# Marshal (Ruby) pipes: sending serialized object to child processes

Tags: ruby, marshalling, pipe

I need to serialize an object in Ruby with Marshal and send it to a sub-process via pipes. How can I do this?

My code looks like the following, and my questions are in comments:

```
data = Marshal.dump(data)
#call sub-process
`ruby -r a_lib -e 'a_method'` #### how to send the stdout to the subprocess?
```

And the a_method looks like:

```
def a_method
  ...
  data = Marshal.load(data) #### how to load the stdout of the parent process?
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can send serialized objects via pipe between different ruby/non-ruby processes!
Let me show you how I do it.
In this example a master process starts a child process, and then child process transmits a simple Hash object using Marshal serialization.

### Master source code:

First it would be useful to declare some helper method **run_ruby** in Process class:

```
#encoding: UTF-8
require 'rbconfig'
module Process
  RUBY = RbConfig::CONFIG.values_at('bindir', 'BASERUBY').join('/')
# @param [String] command
# @param [Hash] options
  def Process.run_ruby(command, options)
    spawn("#{Process::RUBY} -- #{command}", options)
  end
end
```

This code just locates the ruby executable and saves full path into RUBY constant.

> **Important**: If you are going to use **Jruby** or some other executable
>   - you should rewrite this code and provide a path for executing it!

Next, we should start child process.
At this moment we can override **STDIN**, **STDOUT** and **STDERR** for new process.
Let us create a **pipe** and redirect child's **STDOUT** to this pipe:

```
  rd, wr = IO.pipe
  Process.run_ruby("./test/pipetest.rb param1 param2", {:out => wr})
  wr.close
```

Please note the options hash: **{:out => wr}** - It tells spawn command to redirect **STDOUT** to **wr** stream descriptor.

Also, you can specify params (see **param1** and **param2**) in command line.

Note that we call **wr.close** because we do not use it in parent process for this example.

How master would receive object:

```
message = rd.gets         # read message header with size in bytes
cb = message[5..-1].to_i  # message is in form: "data <byte_size>\n"
data = rd.read(cb)        # read message with binary object
puts "Parent read #{data.length} from #{cb} bytes:"
obj = Marshal::load(data) # unserialize object
puts obj.inspect
```

### Child source code:

Now, how serialized object will be transmitted?
At first child will serialize object,
then it will send parent message in the form: `"data <byte_size>\n"`
After that it will send serialized object itself.
Child process will send object to **STDOUT** since we have specified to use this channel as a pipe.

```
#encoding: UTF-8

# obj is an example Hash object to be transmitted
obj = {
    1 => 'asd',
    'data' => 255,
    0 => 0.55
}

data = Marshal::dump(obj)             # serializing object (obj)
$stdout.puts "data #{data.length}"    # sending message header
$stdout.write data                    # sending message itself
$stdout.flush                         # Important: flush data!
```

In the code above child process simply outputs one serialized object and terminates.
But of course, you can program much more complex behavior.
For instance, I start many child processes, each sharing **one and the same pipe** to parent process at **STDOUT**. To avoid problems with two children writing to pipe simultaneously I have to use **system-level Mutex** (not a Ruby Mutex) to control access to this pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IO::pipe`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-pipe) method.

I think you've chosen not the best way to create child process. Backticks does `fork` and `exec` behind the scene and `ruby` command does `fork` and `exec` too. This means that your command:

```
`ruby -r a_lib -e 'a_method'`
```

does the following: fork current process, transform it to shell process, fork the shell process, transform it to ruby process.

I suggest using `fork` method:

```
data = Marshal.dump(data)

reader, writer = IO.pipe
reader.close # parent process will be on the writing side of the pipe
writer.puts data

#call sub-process
fork do
  writer.close # child process can only read from the pipe
  data = reader.gets
  # whatever needs to be done with data
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the sub-process to be run by jruby, whereas the parent process is run by ruby. Can I still use fork?

Comment: No, you can't use `fork` in this case. Neither you can pass pipe object to the child process like this: ``ruby -r a_lib -e 'a_method(#{reader})'``. You can try to use sockets or just write data to a file.

Comment: I was really hoping, that I can use pipes. But thank you very much for the answer, anyway. I think, I just write into a file.