# Object serialization sent through pipe "NoMethodError"

Tags: ruby

I am using pipes in ruby and I am failing to send a serialized object through the pipe.
I am encountering a "NoMethodError" which is wierd because I am sending a struct.
I tried adding a function, but when I call the function I get the same error. 
What is causing this and what is the solution?

Source:

```
reader, writer = IO.pipe

#define the pair object
Pair = Struct.new(:x, :y) do
 end 

#creates, serializes and sends an object
 fork do
     temp = Pair.new(1, 2)  
     temp_str = Marshal.dump(temp)
     writer.puts temp_str
end

#prints it's contents
fork do
    obj = reader.gets
        puts obj.x
        puts obj.y
end
```

Note: I took the basic idea of how things should look from the second answer in this thread:
[Marshal (Ruby) pipes: sending serialized object to child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898528/marshal-ruby-pipes-sending-serialized-object-to-child-processes)

Comment: If you put `:ty` in your struct on purpose it seems rather obvious that a call to `#y` will not succeed, please clarify.

Comment: I didn't it was a typo. It is edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the line `reader.gets` returns a string and not a ruby object. Change the line `obj = reader.gets` to:

```
obj = Marshal.load(reader.gets)
```

And in the first `fork` block, you weren't writing the marshalled object but the object `Pair.new(1,2).to_s`. It should be `writer.puts temp_str` instead of `writer.puts temp`.