# Open another terminal to display information

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if there were a simple way to open a second terminal to display data.  So I have a program running in a terminal, and I was wondering if it'd be possible for that program to open a second terminal to which I could output information for the user to read (leaving the other terminal alone).

Comment: You could log that output information to a file, and in another terminal session tail that file.

Comment: Yeah, was wondering if there was a more direct method.  Like literally puts [terminal 2] "blah".  Nonetheless, I may have to do what you've suggested!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For this, you'd have to get into system specifics. On Linux, for exampe, you could start a child of gnome-terminal.

Comment: We're going to need to your operating system and the terminal (xterm, gnome, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I don't know what operating system you're using or what's your console of choice, but on my Ubuntu 12.10 installation this opened up an `xterm` window with my results:

```
a = "Hello World!"

system(%Q[xterm -hold -e /bin/bash -l -c "echo #{a}"])
```

As for an explanation:

- `-hold` prevents the window from closing as soon as the program executes.
- `-e` specifies what program and its arguments are to be run (the `/bin/bash ...` part.).
- `/bin/bash` invokes the unix shell bash
- `-l` makes bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell
- `-c` will receive console output
- `echo` displays a message on the screen.

Check the man pages for `xterm` and `bash` for more information.

If you add more details, perhaps we can clarify a better answer although, truthfully, I prefer Sergio's answer of outputting to a file and having another console tailing that file.

Comment: Yeah using the same operating system as you!  It works perfectly!  Though I was hoping for a more portable solution.  I shall probably do what Sergio Tulentsev suggested; nonetheless, this answers my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly be inclined to do as Mr Tulentsev suggests in the first comment, but if you'd like to do so from ruby, look [here](http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Process_management) for information on how to start a new process from [ruby](http://ruby-lang.org).

Comment: Let's say he does start a child process. How to bind this child to another terminal session (so that output goes there)?

Comment: One would use the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234119/ruby-pipes-how-do-i-tie-the-output-of-two-subprocesses-together) to do that

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see it. Nowhere in that topic is there a hint of multiple terminal sessions. Anyway, tailing the file is the way to go. Anything else is overcomplicating. :)