# sending message to subprocess with Ruby

Tags: ruby, process, subprocess

Let's say I have a process started from a ruby script like so:

```
pid = spawn('./my_awesome_process')
Process.detach(pid)
```

This process listens on STDIN.
I now wish to read command line input, and send it to the process like so:

```
puts "Please enter input"
input = gets
```

How do I then forwards input to my Process?

Comment: Is the subprocess also Ruby or something else?

Comment: You might take a look at the session gem: https://github.com/ahoward/session

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28966774/846163) about IPC with spawned processes is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`IO.popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-popen), which attaches the subprocess's `stdin` and `stdout` to an `IO` object.

```
IO.popen('rev', 'r+') do |io|
  io.puts "I'm looking at the man in the mirror"
  io.close_write
  puts io.gets
end
```

```
rorrim eht ni nam eht ta gnikool m'I
```